# React file upload behaviour duplicated across components

Tags: reactjs, file-upload, next.js

I have created an image upload thingamajig called `ImageSelector` as a reusable component. It's for a custom CMS where the user first selects a header image, then selects several images for a gallery.

[image]

So the top part of the form uses the `<ImageSelector />` component and the bottom part of the form uses an array of the same component. But for some reason whenever I select an image using the second `ImageSelector` at the bottom of the form, it only changes the image for the first `ImageSelector`.

It surely can't be the components' state that is bound together as I've never experienced that to be a problem, so it must be something to do with the way the browser caches files right? My question is, how can I make a reusable image upload component in React and avoid this duplication behaviour?

### `ImageSelector` component:

#### (styles removed for brevity)

```js
import { useState } from "react";
import { AiFillCamera } from "react-icons/ai";
import styled from "@emotion/styled";

export default function ImageSelector({ placeholder, shape }) {
  const [currentImage, setCurrentImage] = useState();
  const [currentImageUrl, setCurrentImageUrl] = useState();

  function handleChangeImage(e) {
    setCurrentImage(e.target.files[0]);
    setCurrentImageUrl(URL.createObjectURL(e.target.files[0]));
  }

  return (
    <ProfileImage $shape={shape}>
      <div>
        <ProfileImageOverlay $image={!!currentImage}>
          <Label htmlFor="selector-image" $image={!!currentImage}>
            {placeholder ? placeholder : <AiFillCamera />}
          </Label>
          <input
            id="selector-image"
            type="file"
            name="selector-image"
            onChange={handleChangeImage}
          />
        </ProfileImageOverlay>
        {currentImage && (
          <img src={currentImageUrl} alt="selected image" width="170px" height="170px" />
        )}
      </div>
    </ProfileImage>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this duplicate behaviour is what happens when you forget to change the html `id` attribute of subsequent instances of the input field!

Derp.